# Blazor Visual Studio sample template - missing bootstrap.js, references missing blazor.server.js

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

I just created a Blazer (server side) project in Visual Studio. It does include the following in _Host.cshtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<link href="LouisHowe.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And it has in the project the file wwwroot/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css. But...

1. There is no bootstrap.js anywhere in the project. And no <script... /> to include it.
2. It does pull in blazor.server.js but I cannot find that file nor a _framework folder.
3. It created the link to LouisHowe.styles.css but there is no LouisHowe.styles.css file. What's going on with that? (The name of my app is LouisHowe.)

So what's going on with these three issues?

**Updated** to add the LouisHowe.styles.css question.

Comment: Does the project run?  Framework and library files - such as blazor.server.js - are served from virtual directories.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes it runs fine. But I'd like to know where those files are because eventually I need to push this project up to Azure. And the .js and .css files I may want to put on a CDN.

Comment: Publish the solution from VS to Azure and everything gets set up correctly on Azure.  If you split your solution into several project libraries including a UI component library with it's own wwwroot and isolated CSS, the publish process sorts it all for you

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I still like to know what's going on behind the scenes. I dislike the "it's all magic and it works" approach. So... any idea where these files are?

Comment: See my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a project in NetCore you build an executable.  That's obvious with Libraries, but not so obvious when you build a web project.  You're not building a file structure to deploy to a web server.

The type of executable that gets built is defined by the project SDK.  A Blazor Server project is a Web project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

And then what gets built into the executable, and relating to your question, what gets built into the HttpRequest pipeline, is defined by `Program`.

In server

```cs
app.MapBlazorHub();
```

Adds all the handlers to manage the hub sessions and map virtual directory requests to resources.

In the WASM Server this does the same:

```cs
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
```

If you really want to know where `blazor.server.js`is, it's here in the DotNetCore repository and gets included in one of the libraries.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web.JS/dist/Release/blazor.server.js