# Blazor Visual Studio sample template - missing bootstrap.js, references missing .js files

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

I just created a Blazer (server side) project in Visual Studio. It does include the following in _Host.cshtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<link href="LouisHowe.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And it has in the project the file wwwroot/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css. But...

1. There is no bootstrap.js anywhere in the project. And no <script... /> to include it.
2. It does pull in blazor.server.js but I cannot find that file nor a _framework folder.
3. It created the link to LouisHowe.styles.css but there is no LouisHowe.styles.css file. What's going on with that? (The name of my app is LouisHowe.)

So where are these files?

Comment: @maciek Your link is to this question?

Comment: To the other one, which content and title are the same as this one.

Answer (score 1):

1. `bootstrap.js` isn't included.  If you want to use it add it and include it.  Be aware, some of the functionality it provides modifies the DOM directly and causes Renderer Virtual DOM to DOM conflicts and unexpected behaviour in the UI.  `bootstrap.js` functionality can be built directly into the Blazor UI.
2. I've added an answer to your previous question that tries to answer your query more fully.  [Blazor Visual Studio sample template - missing bootstrap.js, references missing blazor.server.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716605/blazor-visual-studio-sample-template-missing-bootstrap-js-references-missing?noredirect=1#comment133587587_75716605)
3. In Solution Explorer *Show All Files*, then drill down *obj > debug > Net7 > scopedcss > bundle* and you'll find the compiler file.  You'll also find all the individual isolation files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="LouisHowe.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

is related with css isolation,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#css-isolation-bundling)

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

is related with basic js functions in blazor such as signalr,it was embeded in the assemblies and couldn't be found directly

If you want try with bootstrap,you could check this [document](https://getblazorbootstrap.com/docs/getting-started/blazor-server)
if you tried with the nuget package, after publishing, you would found the js files under the directory:

```
~\publish\wwwroot\_content\BootstrapBlazor\js
```

when you debugging,you could found it with the uri:
[image]